# Sharing a Windows folder with a Mac computer through a network

Tags: networking, windows-10, mac, domain, windows-domain

I have a Windows computer (which has the files I want to share) that is inside a domain. I want to share a folder on the Windows computer with a Mac that is outside of the domain but on the same internet network. is it possible?

If yes, how?

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity... is the folder on the Mac, or the Windows  computer?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: The question says “I have a Windows computer (which has the files I want to share) …” — it seems clear that the folder on the Windows computer.  What part of that do you find unclear?

Comment: @Scott The original question had too many sentences, and one sentence suggested that the Mac had the folder.  It's been edited for clarity, and I will put in an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Identify the UNC of the shared folder, something like \MYPC\SharedFolder .

2 ) Determine a Windows user who has access to that shared folder from another PC.

3 ) On the Mac, press Command-K .  In the new "Connect to Server" window, enter the UNC name like below.  Note the direction of the slashes is different.

smb://MYPC/SharedFolder

4 ) Press Enter and you should get a login prompt.  Enter the username like "domain\johnsmith" and the password.  You should see the folder pop up with the files you need.